# Spring Context initialization failed with StackOverflowError after upgrading from 5.1.13 to 5.2.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

We have recently upgraded one of our application Spring framework version from *5.1.13.RELEASE* to *5.2.7.RELEASE*.

After the upgrade, Spring application context initialization is failing when try to deploy to a Tomcat (*Apache Tomcat/9.0.7.redhat-10*) server hosted on *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7* but the same application is perfectly running on macOS locally (*Apache Tomcat/9.0.37*).

Also I deployed the same application on a Docker tomcat instance since the issue likely related to the underlying OS (*tomcat:9.0.37-jdk8-corretto*) but couldn't reproduce.

Below is the stack trace from the server.

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restResourceFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/TestServices/webapps/test-controller/WEB-INF/lib/test-client-1.68.0.jar!/path/to/test/common/ResourceManagerBeanPostProcessor.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
                at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:241)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:723)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4602)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:966)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1140)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
                ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
                ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1140)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
                ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
                at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
                at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:172)
                at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
                at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.file(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:90)
                at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.getResource(DirResourceSet.java:101)
                at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
                at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
                at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
                at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2209)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:816)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1261)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
                at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
                at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324)
                at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:65)
                at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)
                at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402)
                at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
                at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
                at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:884)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:710)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:665)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:100)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1140)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1005)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:884)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:710)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:665)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:100)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1140)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1005)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:884)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:710)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:665)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:100)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1140)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1005)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:884)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:710)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:665)
-- omitted the rest
```

What could be the root cause for this behaviour?

----UPDATE 1----

While going through the code I noticed that below change in the Spring's `AbstractBeanFactory.getType` method which seems to be invoking recursively.

**5.1.13**

```java
// Check bean class whether we're dealing with a FactoryBean.
if (beanClass != null && FactoryBean.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
    if (!BeanFactoryUtils.isFactoryDereference(name)) {
        // If it's a FactoryBean, we want to look at what it creates, not at the factory class.
        return getTypeForFactoryBean(beanName, mbd);
    }
    else {
        return beanClass;
    }
}
```

**5.2.7**

```java
// Check bean class whether we're dealing with a FactoryBean.
if (beanClass != null && FactoryBean.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
    if (!BeanFactoryUtils.isFactoryDereference(name)) {
        // If it's a FactoryBean, we want to look at what it creates, not at the factory class.
        return getTypeForFactoryBean(beanName, mbd, allowFactoryBeanInit).resolve();
    }
    else {
        return beanClass;
    }
}
```

----UPDATE 2----

This is a regression in 5.2 release and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25546) is the issue on GitHub.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, it would be better to write a separate, comprehensive answer for everyone's benefit and then later accept your own answer in order to close the question which presently is still listed as unanswered.

Comment: @Lakmal Were you able to solve this issue ? I am getting this in Spring version 5.2.12.RELEASE after a upgrade from spring version 1.0

Comment: @Praveen I was able to fix this by updating Spring AOP version to 5.2.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT